# Angular mat-dialog-title and mat-dialog-actions not sticking

Tags: javascript, html, angular, mat-dialog

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, but my dialog does not seem to be utilizing my sections. This is how I am laying out the dialog:

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xnjbq3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```html
<ng-container ngProjectAs="[mat-dialog-title]">
  <app-dialog-header header="Command Line Arguments"></app-dialog-header>
</ng-container>

<div mat-dialog-content fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="5px">
  <textarea rows="15" class="primary-background"></textarea>
</div>

<div mat-dialog-actions fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
  <button mat-button>Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button color="accent">Save</button>
</div>
```

This is how it looks when I am at the top of the dialog.

[image: Scroll top]

This is how it looks when I scroll to the bottom of the dialog.

[image: Scroll bottom]

According to the documentation when using [`[mat-dialog-title]`](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogTitle) the title should stick to the top, and when using [`[mat-dialog-actions]`](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogActions) the actions should stick to the bottom of the dialog. As seen in the screen shots, that is not happening.

This is how I am opening the modal:

```js
  showCmdArgsDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(CmdArgsDialogComponent, {
      width: '75vw',
      height: '80vh',
      panelClass: 'cmd-args-dialog'
    })
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide StackBlitz repro?

Comment: @RuslanLekhman I have added a link to the StackBlitz

Answer (score 1):

It is not sticky because of dialog options:

```
{
  width: '75vw',
  height: '400px',
}
```

But it still has some issues with `FlexLayoutModule` and `app-dialog-header` component. It works fine with native `mat-dialog-title`. See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f7tgyj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog%2Fdialog.component.html).

Comment: So, to fix this issue, I removed the `height` and moved the flex layout stuff within the `content` and `title` components. That fixed the issue.

Comment: You can see my changes in the StackBlitz I provided.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue might be coming how angular components are [compiled](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16786#issuecomment-521759589)

If you notice in browser elements window (screenshot below) you can see that mat-dialog-title is shown under app-dialog-header element, however, it should be the other way around. As other answer mentions that with native mat-dialog-title this works fine.

[image]